# Upload an Audio File using Graph api

Tags: php, facebook

How to upload an audio file in facebook using graph api in php? use

`feed` or anything i can't figure out how to upload?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know this is not possible. You can only upload photos and videos. But you could host your audio objects on your site and share them via the Opengraph Audio ComplexType. See the reference here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/creating-custom-stories#propertytypes

Comment: i only want to upload audio file or can i upload mp3 file using feed?

Comment: No! As I said, there's no such functionality!